# How can an embedded Google map in an iframe be stored on MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, iframe

I am storing web page contents on a MySQL database using PHP.  If a page has a Google map embedded in it in an iframe construct, the server will return the following message:
*Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /cmp/editpage.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*
When I take the Google map out of the page and then try to store the page contents, there is no problem.
Has anyone come across a similar problem, and have you found any way to resolve it?

Comment: how do you retreive the page in php? it might be a CSP issue here, because the main page cannot retreive the content of an iframe coming from somewhere else for security reasons

Comment: The contents of the page are held in a VARCHAR column in a table in the database, and php simply retrieves the row and, in the process of building the page, displays the contents of the VARCHAR using 'echo'.  I had thought that the problem arose when the page contents were being saved, but you may be on the right track if you're suggesting that it's happening when the page is being re-built  and re-displayed.  When you say it may be a CSP issue, what does that mean?  I am not familiar with the term CSP...

Comment: CSP are the "Content Security Policy", but it will not affect you here (it would affect the page recuperation, not the display, in your case). If the problem is on the page displayed from database, you have to treat iframes as a special case. Because their content is not set by you, but the remote server, you have to recreate the original iframe with the good `src` attribute, and let the content be created from the server. (this means this will work only online, for offline pages, you should maybe disable all iframes)

Comment: Thanks, Kaddath.  You have started me on investigating CSP for possible solutions.  From what I have learned, it appears that I may be able to use the frame-ancestors directive of Content-Security-Policy to specify the Google maps URL as a valid source for iframes.  However, it appears that this directive can't be used in a <meta> tag, but only in an HTTP header.  Despite many searches on the internet, I have not been able to find an example of where and how such a header is coded.  Most sources seem to assume that one has existing knowledge  of them.  Can you help?